# Characterize all the limit points of an open set.

Tags: real-analysis

Characterize all the limit points of an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

The all I know is, any point of the set $U$ is a limit point. Also, I can see the points which are in its boundary is also a limit point, but how will I prove the latter conclusion.

Comment: How is the boundary defined?

Comment: Boundary means $\partial U:=\{ x: B(x,r)\cap U\neq \emptyset, B(x,r)\cap U^c \neq \emptyset, r> 0 \}.$

Comment: Don't have a closed mind here.

Comment: Another way of writing the boundary of $U$ is that it's $\bar{U}\setminus U^{\mathrm{o}}$.